How to set Postgresql.conf so that if postgres shuts down, all transactions are terminated?
I am currently seeing an issue where when Postgres shutsdown, the existing transactions are still lingering around and keep "hanging". I did set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 60000 so it removes any idle transactions.
However, is there a setting where I can have it that if Postgres shuts down or errors out, those transactions gets terminated?
I did find something called exit_on_error but it seems to be for exiting postgres itself if any error occurs, which is probably not it? I can't seem to find any other configuration to do what I want.
TLDR: I want to set in postgresql.conf (or elsewhere) so that if Postgres shutsdown, it automatically terminates all transactions.
So the issue is that we discovered connections "piling up" when the host has connection issues. Ex: The VM with postgres has 10 connections going on. We turn off the networking on the VM to simulate a connection issue. When we go back using "select count(pid) from pg_stat_activity, we see the number of connections still exist and more than before. The goal is that if the host has any issues like network issues and then restarts, we want to terminates those connections prior so they dont "hang". Its less about Client noticing than Server cleaning up previous transactions.
Using postgres v 9.6

It isn't possible for postgresql to have shut down and there still be running transactions. Are you talking about clients not noticing the server has shut down?

So the issue is that we discovered connections "piling up" when the host has connection issues.
Ex: The VM with postgres has 10 connections going on. We turn off the networking on the VM to simulate a connection issue.
When we go back using "select count(pid) from pg_stat_activity, we see the number of connections still exist and more than before.
The goal is that if the host has any issues like network issues and then restarts, we want to terminates those connections prior so they dont "hang".
Its less about Client noticing than Server cleaning up previous transactions.


Add your comment as update to the question text.  2) You are dealing with  client shutdown not the Postgres server shutdown 3) There is no idle_in_transaction_timeout there is idle_in_transaction_session_timeout or idle_session_timeout. 4) Have you looked at TCP settings


Ok it was a typo and I updated.
I am dealing with Postgres server shutdown? If I purposely close the Server's network connection or disrupts it, isn't that on the Server's side?
With the TCP settings,
tcp_user_timeout - is this what I want?

If you are querying the server to see transactions, then it clearly isn't shut down, is it?

No it is shutdown then started up, but the psql command still shows lingering connections. We want to get rid of them.
So ex: current 10 connections - > simulate network outage -> expect 0 connections but seeing 10 or more (could be existing apps trying to connect).
Would the tcp_user_timeout fix it?

Even if this topic is not related to programming: "Using postgres v 9.6" - keep in mind that this version is EOL since nearly three years!

All you need is to set the following parameters in postgresql.conf:

tcp_keepalives_idle = 60

tcp_keepalives_interval = 10

tcp_keepalives_count = 5


Then the server will detect broken connections after approximately 2 minutes, and the backends will die automatically after that time. The only disadvantage is a slight increase in network traffic owing to more keepalive packets being sent on idle connections.

how do i set this in ansible? which file do I need to set for that? I have yaml file I am updating the config file in.

yeah that's what i read. but in my scenario if my network goes down for the server, I want postgres to automatically terminate all transactions vs leaving them hang, how would I do that? is there somewhere I can set that as default?

I misunderstood your question; see my rewritten answer.

So if I understand it correctly, the server will send keep alive at 60,70,80,90,100 seconds and if the client doesn't respond then the connection closes?
Now, if lets say the client is "navigating" a page or filling a form on that page, will the keep alive poll be considered "idle" or the client will respond in the background like "pinging" the ip?
I guess this solution is closest to "if postgres server goes down, terminate all transactions"? It seems this is just general guideline to terminate connections. Thanks!

Keepalive happens on the operating system level. The kernel on the client machine will respond to the keepalive packets, no matter what the application does.

hmm, but if the client is active and the postgres server crashes or network is down, wouldn't the keep alive work as normal when postgres restarts and retries those transactions again? Maybe I am missing something here..

If you change the settings in postgresql.conf, they are persistent and will survive a crash. Note that all that has nothing to do with a server crash, but with a client crash (this is why I misunderstood you at first - I thought you were talking abot database server crashes).

oh i am talking about server crash. The original problem is lets say Postgres has 10 connections, it crashes, now it has 10+ X connections, X being the "new connections". I want to get rid of the 10 connections that are hanging around prior to the crash.

No, if PostgreSQL crashes and restarts, there will be no connections. Connections don't survive a server crash.
